# Problem with QWidget borders in a QGridLayout

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a QGridLayout filled with my custom QWidgets (I'll call them CellWidgets). I want to display a grid between all of the CellWidgets so the columns and rows are clearly visible.

Obviously this isn't done from QGridLayout, as that is simply a holder for widgets that draw themseleves. I made my CellWidgets draw a border by over-riding the paintEvent function like so:

```
QPainter Painter(this);
Painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::white), 2));
Painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
Painter.drawRect(0, 0, width(), height());
```

The QGridLayout spacing is set to 0, however, when it is drawn the grid border has a single width around the edges and double that width between cells, as the border of the cell is effectively being displayed twice.

Any clean way to solve/avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are heading in the wrong direction.

Instead of painting your widget you should try to change the background color of parent widget to get the effect that you want.

Check out this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120109004944/http://www.qtforum.org/article/13876/grid-layout-with-a-border.html) for an example.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not all widgets in my grid will be visible though. I'm making a Calendar widget and if the first day of the month is not Monday then my grid is not a square, it will be some irregular shape. Seems a bit difficult to just show or hide grid lines!